# Show that a function is continuous in one variable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the equation 
$$
F(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)} & \textrm{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \textrm{ if } (x,y) = (0,0). 
\end{cases}
$$
I am trying to show that $F$ is continuous in each variable separately. What does this exactly mean?

Does it mean we have to show that the function 
$$
F(x) = \dfrac{xy_0}{(x^2+y_0^2)}
$$
is continuous for fixed $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$? Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What does $Y$ stand for?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it must be $$\lim_{y\to y_0}F(x,y)=F(x,y_0)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what you have to do (since $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$). THat's easy. If $y_0\neq0$, you have a rational function, which is continuous. And if $y_0=0$, you have the null function, which is continuous too.

If it was not true that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, then you would have to do this for each variable.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $y_0$, let $g_{y_0}(x)=F(x,y_0)=xy_0/(x^2+y_0^2)$. We are just doing this to be totally clear that $g_{y_0}$ is a real function in one variable, and we know how to talk about the continuity of $g_{y_0}$. Well, $g_{y_0}$ is a ratio of continuous functions, so it is continuous unless $x^2+y_0^2=0$. This is only possible if both $x$ and $y_0$ are $0$, so we need to show that $g_0$ is continuous at $0$. If you write out that $g_0$ is, this is trivial.